# Not able to print error statement in Catch block

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have created a procedure and want to print an error message when divide by zero has occured. The execution is coming to the catch block but the error statement is not getting printed.
 PLease help.

```
create procedure pop(@i AS INTEGER, @w AS INTEGER)

    AS
    BEGIN TRY
     SELECT @i/@w;
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
     PRINT 'An Error Has Occurred'
     END CATCH




    exec pop 4,0;
```

Comment: You have tagged your question "mysql", yet it uses SQL Server syntax.  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Ohkey.. Removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it is printing the error message... when I execute it I get:

```
-----------

(0 row(s) affected)

An Error Has Occurred
```

I'm guessing you're maybe executing it in SQL Server Management Studio and has the output set to `Grid`.

Either look at the `Messages` tab, or set the output to `Text`, using `Results to Text` <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>